# How do I remove a stuck moen 1224 cartridge

Tags: shower, faucet

How do you remove a stuck moen 1224 cartridge? My shower is a two handled moen chateau installed in 1994. Getting the collar of the cartridge was no problem. However, the cartridge won't budge. I don't have a puller but have tried needle-nose vice grips, wd 40 and channel locks with no luck.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of a puller (which you can usually borrow from a local hardware store if you buy a cartridge) you can use the handle screw to attach any flat iron bar stock (even a piece of wood maybe) to the stem and twist and pull the cartridge out. I've done it many times.

Answer (score 0):

[The manual for the Moen 1224 cartridge](http://www.moen.com/consumer-support/installation-help/tutorial?id=moen0132) seems to suggest that it just pulls out. Instead of WD-40 try something like CLR. I'd expect you have something like lime or hard water making it stick more than rust. WD-40 won't do much on lime or hard water type corrosion and its not great on rust either.

Are you sure you have a Moen Chateau? It seems that the current line up is a single handle shower fixture. Can you provide a link to the manual or a model number for the Chateau in your shower?

Answer (score 0):

On my bathroom sink I disconnected the water supply lines to the faucet and stuck a 5/16 rod into the water supply holes until they contacted the backside of the cartridges.  Then I gently tapped them out.  Worked great.  Much easier to push out than pull out.  A basic law of physics from an aerospace engineer.

Comment: Craig, you are amazing! I am a widow with three kids at home. My late husband was our plumber, electrician... I’ve been learning quite a lot via the internet these last few years. Today was my first leaking faucet repair. It looked simple enough. Lol. My house is from 1989 and turning off the after was a big ordeal due to corrosion. I spent hours today trying all sorts of tips using vise grips, a wood block, vinegar and wd40. The cartridges were right there ready to be pulled but they would not budge. I was determined not to call a plumber. I was searching for other ideas and (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) saw your common sense approach. Ran upstairs and within minutes they were out! Thank you so much for sharing this approach!